# Using a scrolling text in OLED Adafruit_SSD1305

Tags: c++

I have been in internet for the past week looking for a way of programming a scrolling text (either left or right) using Adafruit_SSD1305 but I only find scrolling commands for Adafruit_SSD1306. Has anyone tried this before? I really need help on this

Comment: Please share links of what you found for the SSD1306. Maybe it can be reused for the SSD1305

Answer (score 1):

The SSD1305 hardware apparently *does* include scrolling support ([SDD1305 datasheet - see section 10](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1305.pdf)) but apparently the Adafruit driver didn't implement it. But The SSD1306 looks so similar to the SSD1305, that if the SSD1306 software driver won't work with it "out of the box" (worth a try!), you could probably compare the two software drivers and back-implement that feature into the the 1305 driver yourself.